# I am confused about tcp demultiplexing?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have studied that server process has "welcome socket" that is waiting for tcp clients for connection to be established.
Once the connection is established, then server process creates a new socket to keep welcome socket open for new clients.
When tcp server receives segment it notes the following four values in the connection-request segment:

1. the source port number in the segment,
2. the IP address of the source host,
3. the destination port number in the segment, and
4. its own IP address.

I am confused that when tcp client sends connection establishment request in the start, it attaches destination port number of server's welcome socket.
then after establishing connection what will it send while delivering data in its header, newly created socket's port number or welcome socket's port number?
And how will client process will come to know about newly created socket's port number?

Comment: Comer& Stevens http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=183420 par10.11.3 tcpdemux() and par11.19 tcplisten() Summary: tcpdemux() has a special case for comparing tcb in listen state. tcplisten() actually clones (most of) a listen tcb into a freshly allocated slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after establishing connection what will it send while delivering data
>   in its header, newly created socket's port number or welcome socket's
>   port number?

The newly created socket's port number will be the same as the original socket's port number.  That is, both sockets will share the original port number.  This does not cause any problem because the the TCP connection is uniquely identified by a 5-tuple of values (protocol#, source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port) and this 5-tuple will be unique to the new TCP connection even though the destination-port subset of it is not.